# Update value of a key in multi-level dictionary; with keys in list using python

Tags: python-3.6

How to update value of a key in dictionary, if have keys in a list in python?

```
# data is dictionary containing multi-level key value
key_list = ['key1','key2','key3']
print(data[key1][key2][key3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flatten_dict import flatten
from flatten_dict import unflatten
# Flattern the data dict
flatten_data = flatten(data)
key_tuple = tuple(key_list)
flatten_data[key_tuple]= newValue # Add your new value here
#  Unflatten the data dict
data = unflatten(flatten_data)
```